# replace repeated value with 0 in string

Tags: r

I am trying to replace consecutive 1's or 2's with 0 in a column. I can't seem to think of a way to do this except a loop, which doesn't really fit with R best practice. Can anyone offer tips for how to do this in an "R way"?

```
set.seed(42)
temp<-sample(c(2,1),10,replace=T)
df<-data.frame(vals=temp)
```

example result:

```
   vals goal
1     1 1
2     1 0
3     2 2
4     1 1
5     1 0
6     1 0
7     1 0
8     2 2
9     1 1
10    1 0
```

my (non-working) attempt:

```
#get all strings with 1
match <- gregexpr("1+", as.vector(df$vals))
#iterate over all matches and create vectors that replace consecutive values with 0 based on the length of match.length
lapply(match,function(y){
  sapply(attr(y, "match.length"),function(x)rep(0,x))
})
```

Just to add another example if needed:

```
val goal
1 1 
2 2
2 0
2 0
1 1
1 0
1 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `diff` to check if one value is the same as the previous:

```
df$goal<- df$vals
df$goal[-1] <- ifelse(diff(df$vals)==0, 0, df$vals[-1])


df
   vals out
1     1   1
2     1   0
3     2   2
4     1   1
5     1   0
6     1   0
7     1   0
8     2   2
9     1   1
10    1   0
```

Or, similarly,

```
df$goal[which(diff(df$vals) == 0) +1L] <- 0
```

Comment: Or, similarly, `df$vals[which(diff(df$vals) == 0) +1L] <- 0`. Feel free to edit this into your answer

Comment: I'll put in my usual plug for  `rle` or my own `seqle` .

Answer (score 3):

Use `rleid` with `duplicated`:

```
library(data.table)
df$goal <- df$vals
df$goal[duplicated(rleid(df$goal))] <- 0
df
   vals goal
1     1    1
2     1    0
3     2    2
4     1    1
5     1    0
6     1    0
7     1    0
8     2    2
9     1    1
10    1    0
```

Or compare the `vals` with the lagged `vals` and assign zero if condition satisfied, for the second example:

```
df$goal <- df$vals
df$goal[df$vals == shift(df$vals)] <- 0

  val goal
1   1    1
2   2    2
3   2    0
4   2    0
5   1    1
6   1    0
7   1    0
```

Comment: If you're using data.table anyway, why not use `setDT(df)[, goal := vals][duplicated(rleid(vals)), goal := 0]`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yep. we can also do that. Nice syntax.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rle` from `base R.`

```
df$vals *!duplicated(inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df$vals),
                                  values <-seq_along(values))))
#[1] 1 0 2 1 0 0 0 2 1 0
```

---

To understand how the `rle` works, it may be better to split up the code,

```
rle(df$vals)
#Run Length Encoding
#lengths: int [1:5] 2 1 4 1 2
# values : num [1:5] 1 2 1 2 1
```

returns a `list` of 2 elements i.e. 'lengths' and 'values' where `lengths` have the length of each repeating adjacent element.  As it is a `list`, we loop using `within.list` to change the 'values' as the sequence of 'values'.

```
within.list(rle(df$vals), values <-seq_along(values))
# Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:5] 2 1 4 1 2
# values : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5  ## changed
```

If we use `inverse.rle`, this returns a vector of 'values' replicated by 'lengths'

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df$vals), values <-seq_along(values)))
#[1] 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 5
```

We get a logical vector of `duplicated` elements using,

```
 duplicated(inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df$vals), values <-seq_along(values))))
 #[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Negate (`!`) it to change `FALSE/TRUE` to `TRUE/FALSE`.

```
 !duplicated(inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df$vals), values <-seq_along(values))))
 #[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

`TRUE/FALSE` are stored as `1/0`.  So, when multiply with `1/0`, the elements that corresponds to 0 will return 0

Comment: This worked great, but I dont really understand the use of `inverse.rle` then `rle` later. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: That is fantastic, Thanks!